# Send image from memory

Tags: python, byte, python-imaging-library, discord.py

I am trying to implement a system for a Discord bot that dynamically modifies images and sends them to the bot users. To do that, I decided to use the Pillow (PIL) library, since it seemed simple and straightforward for my purposes.

Here is an example of my working code. It loads an example image, as a test modification, draws two diagonal lines on it, and outputs the image as a Discord message:

```
# Open source image
img = Image.open('example_image.png')

# Modify image
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
draw.line((0, 0) + img.size, fill=128)
draw.line((0, img.size[1], img.size[0], 0), fill=128)

# Save to disk and create discord file object
img.save('tmp.png', format='PNG')
file = discord.File(open('tmp.png', 'rb'))

# Send picture as message
await message.channel.send("Test", file=file)
```

This results in the following message from my bot:

[image: Discord message with the edited image as result]

This works; however, I would like to omit the step of saving the image to the hard drive and loading it again, since that seems rather inefficient and unnecessary. After some googling I came across following solution; however, it doesn't seem to work:

```
# Save to disk and create discord file object
# img.save('tmp.png', format='PNG')
# file = discord.File(open('tmp.png', 'rb'))

# Save to memory and create discord file object
arr = io.BytesIO()
img.save(arr, format='PNG')
file = discord.File(open(arr.getvalue(), 'rb'))
```

This results in the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 270, in _run_event
        await coro(*args, **kwargs)
    File "example_bot.py", line 48, in on_message
        file = discord.File(open(arr.getvalue(), 'rb'))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x89 in position 0: invalid start byte
```

Comment: What happens if you just try to send the "img" object without saving it on the 1st chunk of code?

Comment: Would you be able to add encoding='utf-8' as an option inside of the open()?

Comment: @YoelNisanov "img" is a "PngImageFile"-object from pillow, which unfortunately isn't something I can directly put into a discord file object.

@Kelo If I omit the 'rb' parameter and instead add the uft8-encoding option, it results in the same error:
`UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x89 in position 0: invalid start byte`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`discord.File`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.File) supports passing [`io.BufferedIOBase`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BufferedIOBase) as the `fp` parameter.
[`io.BytesIO`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BytesIO) inherits from `io.BufferedIOBase`.
This means that you can directly pass the instance of `io.BytesIO` as `fp` to initialize `discord.File`, e.g.:

```py
arr = io.BytesIO()
img.save(arr, format='PNG')
arr.seek(0)
file = discord.File(arr)
```

Another example of this can be seen in the [How do I upload an image? section of the FAQ in discord.py's documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html?highlight=bytesio#how-do-i-upload-an-image).

Comment: While this does work without any error, this way my bot seems to be sending an empty file (Showing up in Discord as a downloadable file with a size of 0 bytes).

Comment: Ah, I forgot Pillow sets the file pointer at the end when it saves. You'll have to seek back to the start of the buffer. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Nice, I actually came to the same conclusion at pretty much the same moment!
Thanks a lot, this works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like @Harmon758 no longer work as expected using `discord.py`

If you pass `io.BytesIO` to `discord.File` you need the parameter filename as well, otherwise the client will not send the image.

So just add the name

```py
arr = io.BytesIO()
img.save(arr, format='PNG')
arr.seek(0)
file = discord.File(fp=arr, filename='<name>')
```

So using `discord.Webhook` for example

```py
import discord

webhook = discord.Webhook.from_url('<webhook>', adapter=discord.RequestsWebhookAdapter())
webhook.send(file=file)
```