# In discord.py, How would I upload an image? (not using link)

Tags: python, image, upload, python-imaging-library, discord.py

This is my code:

```py
@bot.command()
async def spongememe(ctx, meme=''):
        if len(meme) > 10:
                await ctx.send('enter something that is less than 10 characters!')
        else:
                image = Image.open('C:/Users/user/OneDrive/Pictures/blankmeme.JPG')
                font_type = ImageFont.truetype('arial.ttf', 20)
                draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
                draw.text(xy=(70,90),text=meme,fill='red', font=font_type)
                await ctx.send(image)
```

But I just get this output when I run the command: `<PIL.JpegImagePlugin.JpegImageFile image mode=RGB size=486x593 at 0x6042580>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your code, you want to send a `PIL.Image` object, the answer to which is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60010084/6396652)

For your code it would be something like

```py
else:
    image = Image.open('C:/Users/user/OneDrive/Pictures/blankmeme.JPG')
    font_type = ImageFont.truetype('arial.ttf', 20)
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
    draw.text(xy=(70,90),text=meme,fill='red', font=font_type)

    arr = io.BytesIO()
    image.save(arr, format='JPG')
    arr.seek(0)
    imgFile = discord.File(arr)

    await ctx.send(file=imgFile)
```